# Oracle remove special characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a column in a table **ident_nums** that contains different types of ids. I need to remove special characters(e.g. [**.,/#&$-**]) from that column and replace them with space; however, if the special characters are found at the beginning of the string, I need to remove it without placing a space. I tried to do it in steps; first, I removed the special characters and replaced them with space (I used
REGEXP_REPLACE) then found the records that contain spaces at the beginning of the string and tried to use the TRIM function to remove the white space, but for some reason is not working that.

Here is what I have done

```
Select regexp_replace(id_num, '[:(),./#*&-]', ' ') from ident_nums
```

This part works for me, I remove all the unwanted characters from the column, however, if the string in the column starts with a character I don't want to have space in there, I would like to remove just the character, so I tried to use the built-in function TRIM.

```
update ident_nums
  set id_num = TRIM(id_num)
```

I'm getting an error ORA-01407: can't update **ident_nums.id_num** to **NULL**

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

It does work if I add a where clause,

```
update ident_nums
  set id_num = TRIM(id_num) where id = 123;
```

but I need to update all the rows with the white space at the beginning of the string.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Or if it can be done better.
The table has millions of records.

Thank you

Comment: What does *not working* mean?

Comment: @dnoeth the trim function doesn't remove the white space.

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit e.g. .,/$&

Comment: Show your current trim/regexp_replace.

Comment: If column ID_NUM contains only spaces (after replacing special characters with spaces) then TRIM will make it null since Oracle considers an empty string to be a null. Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: @abra indeed, that was the problem. I had two rows with no values but had a white space on it.

Answer (score 3):

Regexp can be slow sometimes so if you can do it by using built-in functions - consider it.

As @Abra suggested TRIM and TRANSLATE is a good choice, but maybe you would prefer LTRIM - removes only leading spaces from string (TRIM removes both - leading and trailing character ). If you want to remove "space" you can ommit  defining the trim character parameter, space is default.

```
select 
     ltrim(translate('#kdjdj:', '[:(),./#*&-]', ' ')) 
from dual;


select 
     ltrim(translate(orginal_string, 'special_characters_to_remove', ' ')) 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Combination of Oracle built-in functions [TRANSLATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm) and [TRIM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) worked for me.

```sql
select trim(' ' from translate('#$one,$2-zero...', '#$,-.','     ')) as RESULT
  from DUAL
```

Refer to this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9215afc8f34d677979f71e0963ca94de)

Answer (score 1):

I think `trim()` is the key, but if you want to *keep* only alpha numerics, digits, and spaces, then:

```
select trim(' ' from regexp_replace(col, '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', ' ', 1, 0))
```

`regexp_replace()` makes it possible to specify only the characters you want to keep, which could be convenient.

Comment: @Abra . . . I am now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone, It this query worked for me

```
update update ident_nums
  set id_num = LTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(id_num, '[:space:]+', ' ') 
  where REGEXP_LIKE(id_num, '^[ ?]')
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you.

```
SELECT id_num, length(id_num) length_old, NEW_ID_NUM, length(NEW_ID_NUM) len_NEW_ID_NUM, ltrim(NEW_ID_NUM), length(ltrim(NEW_ID_NUM)) length_after_ltrim
FROM (
    SELECT id_num, regexp_replace(id_num, '[:(),./#*&-@]', ' ') NEW_ID_NUM FROM 
    (
        SELECT '1234$%45' as id_num from dual UNION 
        SELECT '@SHARMA' as id_num from dual UNION 
        SELECT 'JACK TEST' as id_num from dual UNION 
        SELECT 'XYZ#$' as id_num from dual UNION 
        SELECT '@ABCDE()' as id_num from dual   -- THe 1st character is space
    )
)
```